# too many re renders with add count button

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I have a simple page with buttons which increase the count by 1 or decrease by 1. The solution shows the right way which is by using inline functions for the minus button.However when I changed the plus button to use a regular function, I am getting too many re render.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import randomColor from 'randomcolor'

export default function Playground() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const add = (n) =>{
    setCount(n+1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => add(count)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Fire the add(count) function inside anonymous function like onClick={()=>add(count)}

Answer (score 0):

`<button onClick={add(count)}>+</button>` immediately triggers `add` function when the component render.

Try this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import randomColor from 'randomcolor'

export default function Playground() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const add = () =>{
    setCount(count+1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => add()}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why can't I use regular functions ?

Comment: You can use regular function like this `<button onClick={add}>+</button>` without `()` after `add`, because if you pass `add()` that mean you trigger `add` function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use regular function** or arrow function. But in your case, you were calling the add function every time it re-renders. Consider the difference in the following vanilla JavaScript code snippets:

```
function add() {
  console.log("Add");
}
document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", add);
```

vs

```
function add() {
  console.log("Add");
}
document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", add());  //<--
```

The first one is the way to go.

In the React world, the following implementations are all valid:

```
function ButtonWithArrowFunction() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Clicked");
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Press Me</button>;
}

function ButtonWithInlineArrowFunction() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("Clicked");
      }}
    >
      Press Me
    </button>
  );
}

function ButtonWithRegularFunction() {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("Clicked");
  }
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Press Me</button>;
}

function ButtonWithInlineRegularFunction() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={function handleClick() {
        console.log("Clicked");
      }}
    >
      Press Me
    </button>
  );
}

function ButtonWithHigherOrderFunction() {
  function createHandleClickFunction() {
    return function handleClick() {
      console.log("Clicked");
    };
  }
  return <button onClick={createHandleClickFunction()}>Press Me</button>;
}
```

[image: Edit too-many-re-renders-with-add-count-button]

Answer (score 0):

you can not pass `add()` because it will execute the funcition and will trigger an infinite cycle. Just pass the reference `add` of the method, so it will execute only on the click event

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const add = (n) =>{ 
    setCount(count+1);
  }

return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button  onClick={add}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I still don't get it. I only clicked the function once. What the mechanism behind that will cause the component to be re rendered ?